# Executable File Output

Tags: bash

I'm a beginner of the bash scripting. I need to know how I can create a bash script for the output an executable file.
More clearly, I have an executable file that it is `./word`. The output of this command is not static. So, my script should read this output and put it into the script but how?

Comment: Probably you are looking for [IO redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html "TLDP manual for IO redirect")

Comment: Depends what you want to do with that output. Sometimes you'll want backticks, other times not. Tell us what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If `./word` outputs some shell commands that you wish to run (like ssh-agent does), you can use `eval "$(./word)"`.

If you just want to write the output to a file, use `./word > file`.